# Minimum Knight moves to go from one square to another

Tags: math, min, shortest-path

Is there a mathematical formula one can use to compute the minimum number of knight moves to get between two points in a infinite 2D grid?  I can figure it out using a breadth-first search, but is there a closed-form expression we can use instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the grid finite or infinite? I guess for infinite grids, one can visualize the BFS tree starting at the origin, and try to come up with a formula describing that. But for a finite grid, the boundaries will probably cause lots of special cases.

Comment: we can assume the gird is infinite

Comment: I believe this is the answer you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8778592/1729005

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there is one formula that generates the minimum distands for all pairs of points.

But for some special points there are.
Let A,B be points on a 2D - Grid with `A = (0,0)` and `B = (x,y)` and `dist(x,y)` the minimum number of knight moves.

First of all, the distance is symmetric:

`dist(x,y) = dist(-x,y) = dist(x,-y) = dist(-x,-y) = dist(y,x)`

1. Case: `2x=y` -> `dist(x,2x) = x`
2. Case: `x = 0`

   - Subcase 1: `y = 4k` (k is a natural number)
     -> `dist(x,y) = 2k`
   - Subcase 2: `y = 4k+1` or `y = 4k+3`
     -> `dist(x,y) = 2k + 3`
   - Subcase 3: `y = 4k+2`
     -> `dist(x,y) = 2k + 2`
3. Case: `x = y`

   - Subcase 1: `x = 3k` (k is a natural number)
     -> `dist(x,y) = 2k`
   - Subcase 2: `x = 3k+1`
     -> `dist(x,y) = 2k + 2`
   - Subcase 3: `y = 3k+2`
     -> `dist(x,y) = 2k + 4`

If B (with `0 <= x <= y`) fits in no case, you know at least
`dist(x,y) <= dist(x-k,y-2k) + dist(k,2k) = dist(0,y-2k) + k`
and
`dist(x,y) <= dist(x-z,y-z) + dist(z,z) = dist(0,y-z) + dist(z,z)`

**EDIT:**
I have thought about it a little more. I think the following algorithm computs the minimum moves (Maple Code):

```
dist := proc(x,y)
  global d;
  local temp;

  if x < 0 then x:= -x; fi;
  if y < 0 then y:= -y; fi;
  if x > y then temp := x; x:= y; y:= temp; fi;

  if y = 2*x then return x; fi;
  if x = y then 
    if x mod 3 = 0 then return 2*(x/3); fi;
    if x mod 3 = 1 then return 2+2*(x-1)/3 fi;
    if x mod 3 = 1 then return 4+2*(x-2)/3 fi;
  fi;
  if x = 0 then
    if y mod 4 = 0 then return y/2; fi;
    if y mod 4 = 1 or y mod 4 = 3 then return 3+(y - (y mod 4))/2; fi;
    if y mod 4 = 2 then return 2+(y-2)/2; fi;
  fi;
  if y > 2*x then
    return dist(0,y-2*x) + dist(x,2*x);        
  else
    return dist(2*x-y,2*x-y) + dist(y-x,2*(y-x));
  fi;
end proc:
```

NOTE: this is only correct on a infinite 2D grid.

**EDIT2:** This (recursive) algorithm runs in `O(1)` (time and space) cause it has a constant number of `O(1)` operations and calls it self at most one more time.

**EDIT3:** I thought a littel further and I think this is also correkt on a finite 2D grid, if `A` or `B` are at least 1 row/column away from at least one border.

Comment: in the last 2 cases (in the Maple code), those two return statements should be swapped.

Comment: @DarkTurtle Thanks for pointing this out. I fixed it.